# Run node shebang script from an Azure Pipeline step

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to call a node shebang script from an Azure Pipeline step?

I have a node shebang along these lines but I do not know what is involved in calling this from a pipeline step:

```
const processUrl = async (url, reportDir) => {
  console.log(chalk.yellow(`about to run lighthouse tests against ${url}`));
  try {
    await runCmd('docker',
    [
      'run',
      '--rm',
      '-it',
      '-v',
      `${reportDir}:/home/chrome/reports`,
      '-v',
      `${path.join(process.cwd(), 'lighthouse')}:/home/chrome/reports/config`,
      'femtopixel/google-lighthouse',
      url.replace("localhost", "host.docker.internal"),
      '--config-path',
      './config/lighthouse-config.js',
      '--output',
      'html',
      '--output',
      'json'
    ])
  } catch(err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the shebang character sequence in the top of the file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Now add a Bash task and run the file with the `node` command.

If you want to ensure that Node is installed you can use the task [Node.js tool installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/node-js) task:

```
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 8.x
```

For example, the file `test.js` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const [,, ...args] = process.argv
console.log(`Hi ${args}`)
```

My Bash script is:

```
- bash: 'node test.js shayki'
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, my question is possibly unclear.  I want to know would node be installed or can I guarantee that node is installed on the same vm as the process running the pipeline step

Comment: Oh ok, in the Microsoft Hosted agent Node is installed, if you use your agents you can use the Node installer task, see my update.